# Is Caching ads from Ironsource or any other ad providers to display for the users is good?

Tags: javascript, android, google-play-games, rewardedvideoad, ironsource

I would like to display Rewarded Video ads in my game using ironsource. I would like to know if caching the ads will be good idea to display the ads, since some source says that ads will be refreshed once 10-15 mins, If i also do the same everytime, thats a waste I think, Could someone suggest me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Caching ads is great for user experience and better game flow. 
Ironsource refreshes the ads for you and loading Rewarded Video automatically.
Also, unlike other mediations ironSource loads only 2 networks at the time, keeping the memory and network usage to minimum.